# Ruby: Why is the last element In Array being changed to 1?

Tags: arrays, ruby

My function converts an input binary number into its decimal equivalent. However, when I enter 110 instead of getting 6 (`[2^2 * 1, 2^1 * 1, 2^0 * 0]` ⇒ `[4 + 2 + 0]` ⇒ `6`) I get 7 because the last value in the Array is changed to 1. (`[1, 1, 0]` ⇒ `[1, 1, 1]`). This happens when I save the value at that index using `.to_i` to `valueInt`. At the same time, however, there is an `if` statement that should prevent anything being done to an element with a 0 in it. I am stumped.

```
puts "BinaryArr: #{binaryArr}"

# loops through the array in reverse order and converts the 1's
# to their respective weight by location
binaryArr.reverse.each_index do |index|
  if binaryArr[index] != 0 then
    valueInt = binaryArr[index].to_i
    puts "ValueInt: #{valueInt}"

    val = (2**index)*valueInt
    puts "val: #{val}"

    binaryArr[(binaryArr.length - 1) - index] = "#{val}"
  end
end

puts "WeightArr: #{binaryArr}"

# loops through the arr adding the elements together for the total (decimal value)
decimalInt = 0

binaryArr.each_index do |x|
  thisVal = binaryArr[x].to_i
  decimalInt += thisVal

  if binaryArr[x + 1] == nil then
    break
  end
end

puts "Decimal Value: #{decimalInt}"
```

THE OUTPUT: when 110 is input

```
Binary is: 3 Bits long

BinaryArr: ["1", "1", "0"]

ValueInt: 1    <== why is this a 1 instead of a 0!?!?

val: 1

ValueInt: 1

val: 2 

ValueInt: 1

val: 4

WeightArr: ["4", "2", "1"]

Decimal Value: 7
```

Comment: Note that if `n=157`, its binary representation is given by `arr = n.to_s(2).chars #=> ["1", "0", "0", "1", "1", "1", "0", "1"]`. So if you are starting with `arr`, `arr.join('').to_i(2) #=> 157`. Have a look at the docs for [Fixnum#to_s](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Fixnum.html#method-i-to_s) and [String#to_i](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-to_i).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are indexing the `binaryArr` inside the loop `binaryArr.reverse.each_index do`... `end` to get the value `valueInt`, but you should be indexing the `reverse`. You can set the `reverse` in a variable like this `reverseArr = binaryArr.reverse` before the loop and make sure you iterate over `reverseArr` and indexing it inside the loop. For example:

```
puts "BinaryArr: #{binaryArr}"

reverseArr = binaryArr.reverse

# lops through the array in reverse order and converts the 1's
# to there respective weight by location
reverseArr.each_index do |index|
  valueInt = reverseArr[index].to_i
  puts "ValueInt: #{valueInt}" 
  val = (2**index)*valueInt
  puts "val: #{val}"
  binaryArr[(binaryArr.length-1)-index] = "#{val}"
end
puts "WeightArr: #{binaryArr}"
# loops through the arr adding the elements together for the total(decimal value)
decimalInt = 0
binaryArr.each_index do |x|
  thisVal = binaryArr[x].to_i
  decimalInt += thisVal
  if binaryArr[x+1]==nil then
    break
  end

end

puts "Decimal Value: #{decimalInt}"
```

Of course, you can remove this line: `if binaryArr[index]!=0 then` ... `end`

Answer (score 0):

- `if binaryArr[index]!=0 then` According to the output binaryArr
  contains strings. "a_string" != 0 will aways be true.
- The result of `0**0` is 1.